# Difference between two consecutive number in one element of a combination

Tags: combinatorics

Let $(x_0\textrm{  }x_1\textrm{  }x_2\textrm{  }...\textrm{  }x_k)$ be an element of a combination $\textrm{C}^n_k$. If I denote $d_j$ as the difference between two consecutive $x_i$ where $j=1,2,...,k-1$ such that $x_{i+1}-x_i=d_j$, what is the maximum possible value for $d_j$ (since it depends on the value of $k$ and known that the minimum is $1$) if $x_i<x_{i+1}$? Is there any theorem or books that I can refer to for the basic combinatoric study?
I am looking forward to someone to help me with this problem. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the query. To me, $C_k^n$ is just an integer, namely the one integer one can find at the $k$-th position on the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle. How is that a "combination"? Do you mean that $(x_0, \dots , x_k)$ are $k+1$ integers chosen from the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle?

Comment: I am aware that $\textrm{C}^n_k$ equals an integer. However, what I am focusing on is the possible combinations, not on the total number of possible combinations. For instance, if I have $\textrm{C}^{10}_4$, then one of the possible combinations are $(1\textrm{  }2\textrm{  }3\textrm{  }6$). Also, what I want to know is the maximum possible difference between two consecutive numbers i.e $2-1=1, 3-2=1, 6-3=3$. Or did I have misused any terms in my question?

Comment: I can't really tell if there's an actual misuse, but it's unclear to me. Let me rephrase for you: you're picking $k+1$ integers from the set of integers less than or equal to $n$. From that (ordered) pick, you define $\{\mathbf{d}_j\}$ as the sequence of differences $d_j=x_{j+1}-x_j$. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, you have to clarify what you mean by "an element of a combination $C^n_k$".

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is obtained for $(1,\ldots,k-1,n)$ and it is equal to $n-k+1$.

The fact that it is a maximum is quite obvious. Indeed, if some difference $d$ of neighbors were greater than $n-k+1$, then the total number of elements would be no less than $d+k\leq n-k+1+k=n+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It does work as I want. However, is there any reference or explanation on how to determine that value?

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer.